# Paypal IPN wrong currency in return response

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using Paypal IPN and express payments on my website.

When ever someone decides to pay in GBP it selects my IPN account and when someone selects Euros it selects the Express payments method.

This works 100% of the time for me in testing.

However sometimes the IPN response comes back from Paypal with the currency as EURO and not GBP

They are paying less in Euros than in GBP and were loosing money.

Is the currency changed when the customer arrives on the Paypal website?

Basically they show intent for GBP on my website, but they change to EURO on the Pro hosted solution?

Does this happen? how can I stop it?

Here are some pics:

Sends as GBP:
[image]

Returns as Euros:
[image]

There not from the same transaction it just higlights my problem.

Thanks for any help and advise.